# Shell intervals using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file

```
a 10:10 10:30
b 12:15 13:15
c 16:54 17:54
```

and I need to enter interval for example `10:15` so my output should be `a 10:10 10:30` How I need to do that using `awk`?

Comment: Please do not cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846296/shell-intervals

Comment: Why `awk`? It is not very easy in awk but is trivial using other tools. Also, please delete one of the two duplicate questions you have posted. Keep either this one _or_ the one on [SO].

Comment: You could try: `awk -v myts="10:15" '{if ($2 <= myts && $3 >= myts) print $2,$3}' infile`

Comment: @don_crissti maybe `awk -v myts="10:15" '$2 <= myts && $3 >= myts' infile`

Comment: @don_crissti or OP means: _so my output should be_ **a 10:10 10:30**

Comment: @FloHimself - yeah, I missed the "a"... I guess you're right.

Comment: @terdon what other tools would you use?

Comment: @FloHimself well, now that I've seen what you and don_crissti came up with, I'd use awk :) I had thought the numerical comparison would choke on `10:13` and was instead thinking of using `date -d 10:15 +%s` to convert to seconds and compare that way.

Comment: Would you mind commenting on [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203153/65290)? I think I it answers the question but so far all I got in response was a downvote without any comment. I would like to understand what is wrong about the answer to either improve or delete it.

Answer (score -1):

1) Comparing hours and minutes separately:

```awk
awk -vt="10:15" -F"[: ]" '
  BEGIN{split(t,a,":")}
  $2<=a[1]&&$3<=a[2]&&$4>=a[1]&&$5>=a[2]
' <<_INPUT_
a 10:10 10:30
b 12:15 13:15
c 16:54 17:54
_INPUT_
```

```
a 10:10 10:30
```

2) Converting hours to minutes:

```awk
awk -vt="13:00" -F"[: ]" '
  BEGIN{split(t,a,":");t=60*a[1]+a[2]}
  60*$2+$3<=t&&60*$4+$5>=t
' <<_INPUT_
a 10:10 10:30
b 12:15 13:15
c 16:54 17:54
_INPUT_
```

```
b 12:15 13:15
```

3) Using a function:

```awk
awk -vt="17:15" '
  function f(s){split(s,a,":");return(60*a[1]+a[2])}
  f($2)<=f(t)&&f($3)>=f(t)
' <<_INPUT_
a 10:10 10:30
b 12:15 13:15
c 16:54 17:54
_INPUT_
```

```
c 16:54 17:54
```

Comment: Would you mind commenting on the downvote? I'd be happy to improve my answer and learn something new. But as far as I can tell, it answers the OPs question.